# Delete duplicated old rows and keep only latest mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table

```
id:name:passportnumber:score
1:xxx:123456:99
2:yyy:789012:88
3:xxx:123456:11
4:xxx:123456:44
5:xxx:123456:66
6:xxx:123456:77
```

I want to delete duplicated old rows and keep only latest one which has same passport number

```
id:name:passportnumber:score    
2:yyy:789012:88
6:xxx:123456:77
```

What is the best way without temp table

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to do a self-join to your table and perform the delete:

```
delete t1
from yt t1
inner join yt t2
  on t1.passportnumber = t2.passportnumber
where t1.id < t2.id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7ba8/1)

Comment: Question out of interest, is MySQL smart enough to not make this an almost cartesian product with one row (1<2), one row (1<3), one row (2<3), one row (1<4), one row (2<4) etc?

Comment: @sgeddes It's pretty good, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result/6841479#6841479) is the best answer *ever* posted.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO -- :-)  Touché!

Answer (score 1):

A `LEFT JOIN` on your `DELETE` can do it;

```
DELETE Table1 FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table1 b
  ON Table1.id<b.id 
 AND Table1.passportnumber=b.passportnumber
WHERE b.id IS NOT NULL;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f486d/1).